# How to mock a dependency for an @Autowire object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, autowired

I have an @Autowire object, which has fields whose method calls need to be mocked.

In the main class:

```
@Component
public class Pizza {
     private Tomato tomato;
     private Cheese cheese;

     @Autowired
     private Pizza(Tomato tomato, Cheese cheese) {
        this.tomato = tomato;
        this.cheese = cheese;
     }
     
     public String arrangePizza(tomato, cheese) {
        Sauce sauce = tomato.createSauce();
        combine(sauce, cheese);
        return "Pizza created!"
     }
}
```

In the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestPizza {
     @Autowire
     private Pizza pizza;

     //probably create instances of cheese and tomato here?


     private void testCreatePizza {
        //here I want to mock tomato.createSauce()
        pizza.arrangePizza(tomato, cheese);
     }
}
```

I am trying to mock the method tomato.createSauce() in testCreatePizza using Mockito or EasyMock, but I'm not sure how to do this given that Pizza is Autowired. Would I have to create Autowire instances of `tomato` and `cheese` in the test class? Would spring automatically know to set the constructor to those instances?

Answer (score 1):

Mockito provides the `@Mock` annotation to mock an object and `@InjectMocks` annotation to inject those mocks into an autowired field.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestPizza {

     @Mock
     private Tomato tomato;

     @Mock
     private Cheese cheese;        

     @InjectMocks
     private Pizza pizza;

     @BeforeEach
     void init() {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         when(tomato.createSauce()).thenReturn("Spicy Sauce");
     }

     @Test
     private void testCreatePizza {
        pizza.createPizza(tomato, cheese);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged spring-boot, it's worth also pointing out the @MockBean [annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html). (Relevant quote: "Any existing single bean of the same type defined in the context will be replaced by the mock. If no existing bean is defined a new one will be added.")

That means that, in your test class, you can do

```java
@Autowired
private Pizza pizza;

@MockBean
private Tomato tomato;
```

and then use Mockito's `when` and so on the way you usually do. Compared to the other answer, this way saves you an annotation or two (if you're mocking multiple things), as well as a call to initMocks().

Comment: The `@MockBean` annotation is the preferred solution for Spring: it will register and inject a Mockito mock instance over Spring CDI. 
With the `@InjectMocks` annotation, the dependency injection is done by Mockito, which will work without Spring, but then again needs more boilerplate code for the test setup.